# Allow for mouseover tooltip

Tags: jquery, css

I created a tooltip div to come up when there is a mouseover on the menu button,
The tooltip appears when you mouseover the button and disappears when you mouseout but I am wanting to be able to scroll to the submenu (#submenu.Solutions in this case) and I have no idea how to go about doing this, I have tried setting a timeout and a variable to see if there is a mouseover on the submenu but it just bugged out.

I most recently added mousemove to see if I could do something with the width and height but I'm a bit stumped. So I just left it there for you to see.

```
$('#btnSolutions').mouseover(function() {
    $('#btnSolutions').css("background", "#0f4759");
    $('#submenu.Solutions').css("display", "block");
    var p = $(this);
    var offset = p.offset();
    $("#submenu.Solutions").offset({ top: offset.top + 37, left: offset.left})
}).mousemove(function(e){
    var p = $(this);
    var offset = p.offset();
    $('#submenu.Solutions').height();
    $('#submenu.Solutions').width();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#btnSolutions").css("background", "none");   
    $('#submenu.Solutions').css("display", "none");
}); 
//  
$('#submenu.Solutions').mouseover(function() {

}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#btnSolutions").css("background", "none");   
    $('#submenu.Solutions').css("display", "none");
});
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
JS FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/Lp5Tt/

Comment: Please post the HTML markup. Best would be to put it in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for others to play around with.

Comment: Sure, as per your request here is a JS fiddle of the menu http://jsfiddle.net/Lp5Tt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily use CSS to extend the submenu on mouseover, by moving the submenu `<ul>` into the `<li>` of the parent menu entry, and making the submenu `display: block;` on `li:hover`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uus9N/) (I did not finish styling the submenu, but you should get the idea).

**Problem with this approach**: You can't animate easily with CSS. But you can try to do the animation on the `mouseover` event of the `<li>` element nonetheless.

**Advantages**: No javascript required to display the content. Also, this should work on all modern browsers (maybe not IE 5.5, but that is not a "real" browser anyway :D).

Comment: If an answer helped you solve your problem and you are happy with it, please do not forget to check the green tick on the left to make it the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, however,
for starters, you could trim down, simplify and optimize your code by using css instead of javascript for a large part of this functionality.

example:

```
$('#btnSolutions').mouseover(function() {
    $('#btnSolutions').css("background", "#0f4759");

}.mouseout(function() {
$("#btnSolutions").css("background", "none");

could be replaced with

 #btnSolutions:hover {
    background: #0f4759;
 }
```

you can have the submenu be a child element of the button, and this way, css can be used to hide/show the submenu during :hover on the button

Comment: The colour change on the mouseover was for the purpose of debug, I do have that in Debug. I don't have a problem with displaying anything, the problem I have is when my mouseover runs and the tooltip display I want to allow the tooltip to stay open when my cursor hovers over the tooltip, and I wanted to know how I can go about doing this.

Comment: if i understand correctly,  you dont want the toolltip to close when mouse cursor is moved outside of the 'tooltip-target' element and into tooltip.  in that case- make the tooltip a child element of the target element. you can use absolute positionign and overflow visible to place the tooltip outside of the parent